# When to use "spendieren" rather than "spenden"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

Recently I came across the following sentence

> *"Wie viel RAM hast du denn deiner Kiste spendiert?"*

Roughly I would translate this with *"How much RAM did you dedicated to your box?"*.

What itches me more is that I cannot precisely tell the difference when using  *"[spendieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spendieren)" vs. "[spenden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spenden)"*. Both are listed as synonyms in Duden but I know they are not. When would we use the one or the other? Would the example above also work the same when using *"spenden"* (*"Wie viel RAM hast Du denn deiner Kiste gespendet?"*)?

Comment: "Die Spendierhosen anhaben" is one of my favorite german phrases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Etymologically, both words have the same root while *spendieren* is just an extension of *spenden* by adding the suffix *-ieren* to the root.

> spendieren Vb. ‘großzügig (und reichlich) ausgeben, freihalten’ (17. Jh.), Weiterbildung zu spenden mit dem Verbalsuffix -ieren; vgl. mnd. spendēren, nl. spenderen. <sup>([DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=spendieren))</sup>

However, both means *(ver)schenken* but they are differently used. *Spenden* connotes a bit more that you give something away to someone who is in need of that. You give money to poor people, or you give goods to people who aren't able to afford these stuff.

> Ich spende jedes Jahr 100 Euro an Dritte-Welt-Länder.
>
> Ich spende Kleidung für jene, die nicht das Geld dafür haben.

*Spendieren*, on the contrary, just means that you buy something for someone, e.g. an ice or a beer, just because you like to do them a favor.

> Das Essen spendiere ich dir.

So, the main difference is that *spenden* is for a particular need while *spendieren* is just a favor.

You can translate *spendieren* with *to get or to buy [sb.] sth.* while *spenden* is translated with *to donate or to contribute sth to so/sth* (where sth is e.g. an organisation).

In your example, however, the use of *spendieren* is figuratively. Actually, you can't "make a gift to your computer". Nonetheless, the usage of *spendieren* is more accurately here than *spenden*, although it might be possible to use *spenden* if you want to express that your computer was really in need of the extension of memory. But I'd prefer *spendieren* over *spenden* in figurative use.

Anyway, I wouldn't use this expression. It sounds a bit strange to me. I'd say something along these lines:

> Mit wie viel RAM hast du deine Kiste ausgestattet?
>
> Wie viel RAM hast du in deiner Kiste installiert?

---

Some recent examples:

> Noch nie hat die Finanzbranche in den Vereinigten Staaten so viel Geld ausgegeben, um einen Wahlkampf zu beeinflussen. Banker, Hedgefonds-Manager und Vermögensverwalter spendeten bislang über 160 Millionen Dollar. <sup>([zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/2012/38/USA-Banken-Wall-Street-Obama))</sup>
>
> Warum aber verzichtet Romney darauf, die ganzen 4,02 Millionen Dollar, die er für gemeinnützige Zwecke gespendet hat, steuermindernd geltend zu machen? <sup>([zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/politik/2012-09/mitt-romney-steuererklaerung-2011))</sup>
>
> Das erste Mal seiner Flamme (= Freundin, Anm. von mir) einen Amarena-Becher spendieren. <sup>([zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/2012/34/Eis-Mannheim))</sup>
>
> Menschen laden ihn zum Essen ein und spendieren ihm Saft für seinen Roller, den Vianney liebevoll Gogo nennt. <sup>([zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/auto/2012-06/elektroroller-frankreich-tour))</sup>

Comment: Ich glaube fast, der Unterschied zwischen den Wörten intendiert eher den Unterschied der Situation beim Spender/Spendierer. Es induziert ein anderes Bild wenn ich schreibe "Der Milliardär Bill Gates spendete der Welthungerhilfe 50 Millionen" als wenn ich schreibe: "Der Milliardär Bill Gates spendierte der Welthungerhilfe 50 Millionen" - das zweite drückt eher eine Art Amüsiertheit beim edlen Spender aus... (cont)

Comment: (cont) Umgekehrt kann man das auch mit dem RAM finden. Man würde erwarten "Ich muß jährlich meinem Rechner 1 GB RAM mehr spendieren" weil man diese lockere Sprechweise "so kennt". Wenn einer das mit spenden ausdrückt:"Ich muß jährlich meinem Rechner 1 GB RAM mehr spenden" - dann lese ich da eher heraus, daß er außerdem 'rüberbringen will, daß es ihn nicht leicht fällt. (Aber das ist hier völlig subjektives Stilempfinden)

Answer (score 19):

> spenden

is mostly used in the sense of

> to donate

So, you would say something like:

> Last year I donated 200€ to charity.

Which is

> Letztes Jahr habe ich 200€ für wohltätige Zwecke gespendet.

Whereas

> spendieren

means something like

> to spend on / to pop for / to treat sb. to sth.

So, to answer your last question: I would not use `spenden` in this context.